# Flink SQL timestamp to milliseconds

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

Can someone point me if there is a way to convert Flink SQL TIMESTAMP(3), TIMESTAMP_LTZ(3) to milliseconds without involving **UDF**?

Or maybe there is a way to represent Kafka Event Time in milliseconds using Table API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @David Anderson and Flink Error Messages I found this solution:

```
1000 * UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CAST(eTime AS STRING)) + EXTRACT(MILLISECOND FROM eTime)
```

Maybe in the future we'll have a built-in function for it...

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this might work:

```sql
SELECT (1000 * EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ts)) + EXTRACT(MILLISECOND FROM ts)
```

Comment: Thanks David. Unfortunately I have `org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: EPOCH is unsupported now.` probably it wasn't implemented in Flink 1.14.6. I can find it in 1.16 documentation.

Comment: Perhaps you can get it done with a CAST of some sort?